# Twitter shared post appear twice

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have integrated posting to twitter using twitter4j.

i have two devices samsung S3 - Android 4.3 and Sony Xperia Z - Android 4.4.

When i try to share from S3 the post appears twice, but if i post from xperia z it shows only once.

What might be the issue ?

```
try {
                    if (verifier != null) {
                        AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                requestToken, verifier);
                        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

                        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(mMessage);
                        File imageFile = new File(mImageLocation);

                        if (imageFile != null) {
                            status.setMedia(imageFile);
                        }
                        twitter.updateStatus(status);
                    }
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    Log.d("Twitter", e.getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code :

```
if (verifier != null) {
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                            requestToken, verifier);
                    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

                    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(mMessage);
                    File imageFile = new File(mImageLocation);

                    if (imageFile != null) {
                        status.setMedia(imageFile);
                    }

                    String strStatus = String.valueOf(status);      

                   if(strStatus !=null){

                     twitter.updateStatus(status);
                     strStatus = null ;
                   }

                }
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.d("Twitter", e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Nope, its still the same the post appears twice

Comment: The thing is twitter.updateStatus(status); is called twice but i dont know why?